# sp_sqlexec - To many arguments specified

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get the error 'Too many arguments specified' but cannot find the problem

Any help would be greatly appreciated

The 3 parameters are specified at the begin of the procedure

```
DECLARE
 @WhereStatment nvarchar(500),
 @ParamList nvarchar(500) = N'@p1 int, @p2 varchar(256), @p3 int'

SET @WhereStatment = ''

-- Check for Status Filter
IF @StatusFilter <> 'All'
SET @WhereStatment = @WhereStatment + ' EntryStatus =  @StatusFilter'
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @StatusFilter = 'Invoiced (Complete)'
SET @WhereStatment = @WhereStatment + ' EntryStatus <> @StatusFilter'
END

-- Check for User Filter
IF @UserFilter > 0 
SET @WhereStatment = @WhereStatment + ' AND EobID = @UserFilter'

-- Check for Warehouse Filter
IF @WarehouseFilter > 0
SET @WhereStatment = @WhereStatment + ' AND WarehouseNumber = @WarehouseFilter'

-- Add WhereStatement
Set @WhereStatment = '
SELECT 
tblWCS_SQE_Entries.RowID, SaleNum, tblWCS_Company_UserAccounts.Fullname, Ets

FROM tblWCS_SQE_Entries

INNER JOIN tblWCS_Company_UserAccounts
ON tblWCS_SQE_Entries.EobID = tblWCS_Company_UserAccounts.RowID

WHERE  
'
+ @WhereStatment;

EXEC sp_sqlexec @WhereStatment, @ParamList,
                @p1 = @UserFilter, 
                @p2 = @StatusFilter, 
                @p3 = @WarehouseFilter
```

Comment: sp_sqlexec is not used anymore https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/554d6373-8a22-4b10-8744-df13e5415f84/spexecutesql-vs-spsqlexec?forum=sqlgetstarted use sp_executesql. Here you have an example on how to use it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: `sp_sqlexec` is deprecated, should be using `sp_executesql`.  Your param list supplies `@p1, @p2, @p3` but your query references `@StatusFilter, @UserFilter, @WarehouseFilter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sp_sqlexec` stored procedure indeed has only one parameter. Probably you want `sp_executesql` instead.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. That and as MatBailie commented, the parameters referenced was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = '
SELECT tblWCS_SQE_Entries.RowID, SaleNum, tblWCS_Company_UserAccounts.Fullname, Ets
FROM dbo.tblWCS_SQE_Entries
JOIN dbo.tblWCS_Company_UserAccounts ON tblWCS_SQE_Entries.EobID = tblWCS_Company_UserAccounts.RowID
WHERE '
+ CASE WHEN @StatusFilter = 'All'
    THEN ' EntryStatus <> ''Invoiced (Complete)'''
    ELSE ' EntryStatus =  @StatusFilter'
  END
+ CASE WHEN @WarehouseFilter > 0 THEN ' AND WarehouseNumber = @WarehouseFilter' ELSE '' END
+ CASE WHEN @UserFilter > 0 THEN ' AND EobID = @UserFilter' ELSE '' END

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
                     , N'@p1 int, @p2 varchar(256), @p3 int'
                     , @p1 = @UserFilter
                     , @p2 = @StatusFilter
                     , @p3 = @WarehouseFilter
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a lot cleaner. Was looking for a way to do the where clause as you did it. Did not think to just add strings rather than hard code it. Very helpful.